# How can I multiply each column with the other columns of the Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe I would like to multiply each column with the other columns one by one and return each new column as a new column to that dataframe. For example

```
A B C
1 2 3
2 4 4
1 2 5
```

then

```
A B C A*B   A*C     B*C
1 2 2  2     3       6
2 4 8  8     8       16
1 2 2  2     5       10
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a brute force method, but it should do the job. `permutations()` generates all the column permutations. The inner `sorted()` together with `set()` merges `('A','B')` with `('B','A')`, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1],[2,4,2],[3,4,5]],columns=['A','B','C'])

for c1,c2 in sorted(set([tuple(sorted(s)) for s in itertools.permutations(df.columns,2)])):
  df['{0}x{1}'.format(c1,c2)] = df[c1]*df[c2]

print df
```

Comment: Of course instead of using `permutations`, `sorted` and `set` a better solution is to use `combinations` as shown by Matt below. What was I thinking of? :-)

Answer (score 1):

`combinations` from `itertools` does what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

for c1, c2 in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    df['{0}*{1}'.format(c1,c2)] = df[c1] * df[c2]
```

`df` now contains your desired columns:

```
   A  B  C  A*B  A*C  B*C
0  1  2  1    2    1    2
1  2  4  2    8    4    8
2  3  4  5   12   15   20
```

If you don't want to keep everything in memory you can calculate the product on the fly:

```
for c1, c2 in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    s = df[c1] * df[c2]
    # Do whatever is necessary with s
    print c1, c2, s.apply(lambda x: x ** 0.5).mean()
```

Output:

```
A B 2.56891410075
A C 2.29099444874
B C 2.90492554737
```