# Pandas create multiple columns based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge df (720 columns) with this structure:

```
id A B C
1  1 0 1
2  1 0 1 
3  1 1 1
```

I would like to create a new df, based on calculations such as:

```
if A and B = 1 then  v1 = 1
if A and C = 1 then  v2 = 1
if A and D = 1 then  v3 = 1
if A and XX = 1 then v719 = 1

id V1 V2 
1  0  1
2  0  1 
3  1  1
```

As I need to iterate A vs B and C (in reality A vs 719 columns) I looking for a way to write this code without doing something like this for ALL columns

```
df.loc[((df['A'] == 1) & (df['B'] == 1)), 'v1'] = 1
df.loc[((df['A'] == 1) & (df['C'] == 1)), 'v2'] = 1
df.loc[((df['C'] == 1) & (df['D'] == 1)), 'v2'] = 1
df.loc[((df['A'] == 1) & (df['XX'] == 1)), 'v719'] = 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For your question we can do , since 1 * 1 = 1

```
s=df.loc[:,'B':].mul(df.A,axis=0)
   B  C
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  1  1
s.columns=np.arange(s.shape[1])+1
df=df.join(s.add_prefix('v_'))
```

Comment: Maybe I've oversimplified. Actually conditions are more like:

if A = 1 and B = 2 then  v1 = 1

etc...

Comment: @EGM8686 Is it two for all columns or just `B`?

Comment: Tricky part is that is for ALL columns. So in this case I end up with 3 dfs (A with B, A with C and B with C)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the values. B =2, C =2 or would C = 3 being it's the third column.

Comment: Values could change, so provided solution does not work as it assumes that you can do 1*1

Comment: @EGM8686 The provided solution in only multiplying against A, but you want all combinations. I searched around and I think this should get you going: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229892/how-can-i-multiply-each-column-with-the-other-columns-of-the-pandas-dataframe